# Re-run reactive helper when $scope changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, reactive-programming, angular-meteor

I have a reactive data source in Angular-Meteor and would like to find a way to make the reactive function re-run after I change another of the $scope values. Here, I want to change the sort order based on $scope.model.sort:

```
angular.module('...').controller('MyCtrl', [...], function(...){

    //Subscribe
    $scope.subscribe('articles');

    //Init
    $scope.model = {
        sort: 1,
        ...
    }

    //Reactive definitions
    $scope.helpers({
        articles: () => {
            console.log("+ articles");
            return Articles.find({...}, {sort: {colToSort: $scope.model.sort} });
        }
    });
```

I then change the sort order in the html or by calling a function:

```
ng-click="model.sort=-1"
ng-click="setSort(-1)"
```

JS

```
    $scope.setSort = function(sort) {
        console.log("+ setResourcesSort(%s)", sort);
        $scope.model.sort = sort;
    }
```

Neither of these ways seems to re-run the reactive helper. Is it possible to make the reactive helper re-run when the referenced `$scope.model.sort` is changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you need add `getReactively`

```js
  $scope.model = {
        sort: 1,
        ...
    }

    //Reactive definitions
    $scope.helpers({
        articles: () => {
            console.log("+ articles");
            return Articles.find({...}, {sort: {colToSort: $scope.getReactively('model.sort')} });
        }
    });
```

Reading api [document](http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.6/get-reactively) for more detail

Answer (score 0):

The helper needs to be in a reactive area, right now it does not seem to be so. You have $scope as a helper but not linked to anything? So if you put it in a template helper, it will run whenever scope changes, but as a stand alone helper (as it seems right now) it will not re-run automatically when the data context changes.

Comment: I think you are referring to the blaze template helpers however this code is not written for blaze, but for angular-meteor and so is written in that syntax.